# The sum: $ 1+ {n \choose 1}\cos{\theta} + {n \choose 2}\cos{2\theta} + …. + {n \choose n}\cos{n\theta} $ equals

Tags: complex-numbers

The sum:

$$ 1+ {n \choose 1}\cos{\theta} + {n \choose 2}\cos{2\theta} + …. + {n \choose n}\cos{n\theta} $$
equals

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove: $1+{n\choose 1}\cos\phi+{n\choose 2}\cos2\phi+...+{n\choose n}\cos n\phi=2^n\cos^n\frac{\phi}{2}\cos\frac{n\phi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495676/prove-1n-choose-1-cos-phin-choose-2-cos2-phi-n-choose-n-cos-n-phi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the real part of ${(1+e^{i\theta})}^{n}$.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. Are results like these to be remembered? What should I do to make such observations?

Answer (score 3):

It is $2^n cos^n(\theta/2) \cos(n\theta/2).$